# Как включить преобразование хвостовой рекурсии в C#

Tags: c#

```
static int Ackerman(int x, int y, Func<int, int> k)
{
    if (x == 0)
        return k(y + 1);
    else if (y == 0)
    {
        return Ackerman(x - 1, 1, k);
    }
    else
    {
        return Ackerman(x, y - 1, r => Ackerman(x - 1, r, k));
    }

}
```

при значениях параметров 3, 5 переполнение стека.
Как в компиляторе включить функцию преобразования концевого вызова?

Answer (score 9):

Принудительно - никак. Для x64 JIT умеет генерировать tail call даже без .tail префикса в IL, но делает это на свое усмотрение, [с некоторыми ограничениями](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davbr/2007/06/20/tail-call-jit-conditions/), но только при включенной оптимизации (Release, без подключенного отладчика).

Попробуйте переключить в Release конфигурацию, выбрать платформу x64, и запустить без отладчика - ваш код отработает.

Proposal по tail call на github: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2544

Comment: Пробовал собрать релиз, тоже переполнение стека, а у Вас получилось?

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку. Если в релизе включить x64 - цель платформы, все работает!!!

Comment: @ИгорьШевченко да, сорри, забыл упомянуть про x64 - дописал в ответ.